# Securing an IoT device along with TLS

Tags: security, embedded, iot, rtos, texas-instruments

I am developing an IoT device that uses TI's tm4c129encpdt microcontroller, cc3100 wifi chip and TI RTOS, and I am using TLS for secure communication with the server (HTTPS). 
I just want to make my device more secure by adding some authentication methods. I am already assigning tokens to the device through a server. 
Is there any standard way to add authentication method to an IoT device based on which I can assure to my clients that it has secured communication and authentication method?

Thanka and Regards
Akhilesh Gangwar

Comment: Is the HTTPS server running on the IoT device or is it just a HTTP client? In both cases make sure that "TLS" does include a "still secure" version like TLS 1.2/1.3, not only the old deprecated versions like 1.0/1.1.

Comment: Both server and client are using TLS 1.2.  I am looking to add more security like secure authentication. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 2-way authentication using TLS.